# Set Pycharm path to same as Terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

In terminal I have Anaconda installed, so numpy etc is fine to import.  In Pycharm I get this error message when trying to run code with the import for numpy:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4` `/Users/joelmcleod/python/test.py`
    `Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/Users/joelmcleod/python/test.py", line 2, in <module>`
`import numpy as np`
`ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

How can I set Pycharm to use the Anaconda version of Python as well to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, run `which python` to see what python executable you're using.  In PyCharm, follow these instructions to set the python interpreter: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html